# Why can't `round` be defined for non-floats?

Tags: python, class, python-2.7, rounding

Given a simple class like

```
class Vector(object):
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value
    def __abs__(self):
        return math.sqrt(sum([x**2 for x in self.value]))
    def __round__(self, *n):
        return [round(x,*n) for x in self.value]
```

why does `abs(Vector([-3,4]))` correctly yield `5` while `round(Vector([-3.1,4]))` complains with a `TypeError: a float is required` instead of the desired `[-3,4]`, and how can this be fixed?

I know `round` should usually return a float, but for a vector as in this example there is probably no ambiguity on the possible meaning, so why can this not be simply overridden? Do I really have to subclass `numbers.Real`, or define `Vector(...).round(n)` instead?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `__round__` special method was only introduced in Python 3. There is no support for the special method in Python 2.

You'll have to use a dedicated method instead of the function:

```
class Vector(object):
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value

    def round(self, n):
        return [round(x, n) for x in self.value]
```

or you'd have to provide your own `round()` function:

```
import __builtin__

def round(number, digits=0):
    try:
        return number.__round__(digits)
    except AttributeError:
        return __builtin__.round(number, digits)
```

You could even monkey-patch this into the `__builtins__` namespace:

```
import __builtin__

_bltin_round = __builtin__.round

def round(number, digits=0):
    try:
        hook = number.__round__
    except AttributeError:
        return _bltin_round(number, digits)
    else:
        # Call hook outside the exception handler so an AttributeError 
        # thrown by its implementation is not masked
        return hook(digits)

__builtin__.round = round
```

Comment: I see, in that case I should tag the question [tag:python-2.7] as well... Does the same apply to `math.floor` et al.? And is there no `from __future__ import` to fix this?

Comment: No, unfortunately there is no `from __future__` switch that'll enable that behaviour.

Comment: Bummer :-( That's one very convincing argument to switch to Python 3 for me then...

Comment: @TobiasKienzler Alternatively you could just monkey patch the `round` function (even though that's bad style)

Comment: Note to self: _First_ store a reference to the original `round`, _then_ monkey-patch the wrapper which calls the _stored_ reference - otherwise it's [turtles all the way down](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turtles_all_the_way_down)... **edit** @MartijnPieters I see you also noticed that :-7

Comment: I guess a less evil behaviour could be achieved by trying the builtin version first and only on a `TypeError` try the other one. But hey, doesn't this code basically do what a `from __future__ import round` would be expected to do?

Comment: Is `import __builtin__` actually necessary? One can simply access the original `round` via `__builtins__.round`

Comment: It is a CPython implementation detail that that is a available, really.

Comment: Ah thanks, I found [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11181519/321973). So in fact one should _never_ use `__builtins__` (with s), correct? **edit** Except in Python3, where [`__buildin__` is called `buildins`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9047745/321973), but Python3 implements the "correct" `round` anyway...

Comment: @TobiasKienzler: exactly; and `__builtins__` (with an `s`) is a dictionary everywhere, *except* in the main script (`__name__ == '__main__'`) where it is a module object.. Using `__builtin__` makes it easier as you don't have to remember to handle either case.