# Solution wide constants

Tags: c#, python, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, global-variables

I have a VS2015 solution with a large `c#` project and a `python` helper project.  Is there a simple way to have **solution-wide constants** that I could access from both projects?  If not, it would just hamper my maintainability, but I thought I'd ask.

Comment: try locals() and globals()

Comment: If you really do mean constants, I'd put them in a config file.

Comment: @EdPlunkett, Thanks, that's what I'm doing now

Comment: In that case I'd retitle the question to "Solution wide constant constants"

Comment: Python doesn't have truly global (inter-module) variables or constants, and even if it did they would be defined differently since it's a different language that C#, The most portable way to do it is with a config file that can be read and processed by both Python and C#. On the Python side, if you really want things to available to to all modules without importing, you _could_ modify the `__builtin__` module (note the name has no `s` in it), although doing so might be a [bad idea](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6965111/355230).

Comment: @anonymous sorry, it's the weekend! Good thing I decided to get the app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a separate file for maintaining your constants with some structure which could be accessed by both C# and Python. For example: [JSON](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON), [YAML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YAML), etc. Read this file to load configuration from both projects