# How to create a function that does not require import? (In Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x

I know there are many built-in functions in Python that we can use without calling `import xxx` first, e.g., `map`, `range`, `len`, etc.

Is there a way I can build such a function myself too? Ideally, I would like to define a function called `my_func`, and call `my_func` anywhere in my project without calling `from xxx import my_func`.

Answer (score 0):

```
import builtins

def my_func(): ...

builtins.my_func = my_func
```

Now you can use it anywhere without importing.

Comment: Note this is generally a [bad idea](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6965111/2980246)...