# Can I use __init__.py to make imports available globally?

Tags: python, package, python-import

I have the following in my `__init__.py` to avoid the repeated import of the typing library:

```
from typing import Dict, List, Tuple
```

yet, when I use `Dict` in my package code, it raises a `NameError 'Dict' is not defined`.

Do I have to include the above import statement explicitly in every class?

Note that typing is not my own module, so it is not inside the package directory

Comment: You need to include it in every module that uses it.

Comment: OK, thanks, I'll live with it

Comment: Generally speaking, one can add new built-ins by modifying the `builtins` module on-the-fly. See [How to add builtin functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6965090/how-to-add-builtin-functions).

Answer (score 0):

The import statement has to go at the top (not always) of the code you are programming every time.

__init__.py

```
from typing import Dict, List, Tuple
    ^ this will not affect main.py 
Dict(blah)
...
```

Main.py

```
from typing import Dict, List, Tuple
Dict(jjjj)
```

Comment: "has to go at the top (not always)" — huh?

Comment: that is straight forward with a script, but the package only defines classes, and I don't want the end-user to have to declare all imports when they use the package

Comment: It can also go in the middle of the program as long as it is in front of ```Dict()``` @martineau

Comment: Then use ```from typing import *``` @Uliw

Comment: No adding it to main.py

Comment: Halleluja, I did not see the forest for all the trees! Upon import, all module code is executed, even so, no class is instantiated yet. Thanks!