# Python run multiple files interactively

Tags: python, python-3.x

In python, you can run `python3 -i some_file.py` to run `some_file.py`, then open an interactive session in the file, allowing you to debug and such.

I have my own file full of functions and things to use for testing stuff out `python3 -i ~/testing_functions.py`.

Is there a way I could use this in another file: `python3 -i some_file.py -i ~/testing_functions.py`

```py
# a.py
a = "A"

# b.py
b = "B"
```

```sh
# in the shell
$ python3 -i a.py -i b.py
>>> print(a)
A
>>> print(b)
B
>>> pribt(a+b)
AB
```

When I try `python -i file.py -i other.py` is does not work, and neither does `python -i file.py other.py`

I would like to avoid just importing if possible, as I don't know what directory I will be in or file I will test, and relative vs. absolute imports confuse me.

Comment: Welcome to Python! Have you tried `import testing_functions` at the start of `some_file.py` instead?

Comment: The issue is that I'm not always going to use this on the same file. I want to use it whenever I am debugging or trying anything with any python file, without having to edit every time or deal with making sure testing_functions is in sys.path.

Comment: Well you can add the module to the python built-ins as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6965111/10961342). But this can be very confusing if you rename the variable by accident.  A better approach would be to either use unit testing ([starters guide](https://realpython.com/python-testing/)) for your debugging, or using an IDE such as Pycharm where you can import the module at run time (or during debugging).